# Why is my custom MKTileOverlayRenderer drawing the same tile in multiple places?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, overlay, mktileoverlay

So I'm writing a MapKit-based app which draws an overlay over the map. However, a lot of the overlay drawing is dynamic, such that tile which gets drawn is frequently changing, so I've implemented a custom MKTileOverlay and a custom MKTileOverlayRenderer. The first one to handle the url-scheme for where the tile images are stored, and the second to handle the custom drawMapRect implementation.

The issue I'm running into is that I seem to be drawing the same tile image in multiple locations. Here's a screenshot to help you visualize what I mean: (I know the tiles are upside-down and backwards and I can fix that)
[iOS Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp2vg.png)

I've changed certain tile images such that they're a different color and have their tile path included. What you'll notice is that many of the tile images are repeated over different areas.

I've been trying to figure out why that might be happening, so following my code path, the overlay starting point is pretty standard--the ViewController sets the addOverlay() call, which calls the delegates' mapView(rendererForOverlay:) which returns my custom MKTileOverlayRenderer class, which then attempts to call my drawMapRect(mapRect:, zoomScale:, context). It then takes the given map_rect and calculates which tile that map_rect belongs to, calls the custom MKTileOverlay class's loadTileAtPath() and then draws the resulting tile image data. And that's exactly what it looks like my code is doing as well, so I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. That said, it works perfectly fine if I'm not trying to implement custom drawing and use a default MKTileOverlayRenderer. Unfortunately, that's also the crux of the app so not really a viable solution.

For reference, here's the relevant code from my custom classes:

My custom MKTileOverlay class

```
class ExploredTileOverlay: MKTileOverlay {

var base_path: String
//var tile_path: String?
let cache: NSCache = NSCache()
var point_buffer: ExploredSegment
var last_tile_path: MKTileOverlayPath?
var tile_buffer: ExploredTiles

init(URLTemplate: String?, startingLocation location: CLLocation, city: City) {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
    self.base_path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/" + city.name + "_tiles")
    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(base_path)) {
        try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(base_path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    }

    let new_point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location.coordinate)
    self.point_buffer = ExploredSegment(fromPoint: new_point, inCity: city)
    self.tile_buffer = ExploredTiles(startingPoint: ExploredPoint(mapPoint: new_point, r: 50))
    self.last_tile_path = Array(tile_buffer.edited_tiles.values).last!.path
    super.init(URLTemplate: URLTemplate)
}

override func URLForTilePath(path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> NSURL {
    let filled_template = String(format: "%d_%d_%d.png", path.z, path.x, path.y)
    let tile_path = base_path + "/" + filled_template
    //print("fetching tile " + filled_template)
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(tile_path) {
        return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "")
    }

    return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tile_path)
}

override func loadTileAtPath(path: MKTileOverlayPath, result: (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    let url = URLForTilePath(path)
    let filled_template = String(format: "%d_%d_%d.png", path.z, path.x, path.y)
    let tile_path = base_path + "/" + filled_template
    if (url != NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tile_path)) {
        print("creating tile at " + String(path))
        let img_data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "small")!)!
        let filled_template = String(format: "%d_%d_%d.png", path.z, path.x, path.y)
        let tile_path = base_path + "/" + filled_template
        img_data.writeToFile(tile_path, atomically: true)
        cache.setObject(img_data, forKey: url)
        result(img_data, nil)
        return
    } else if let cachedData = cache.objectForKey(url) as? NSData {
        print("using cache for " + String(path))
        result(cachedData, nil)
        return
    } else {
        print("loading " + String(path) + " from directory")
        let img_data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(contentsOfFile: tile_path)!)!
        cache.setObject(img_data, forKey: url)
        result(img_data, nil)
        return
    }
}
```

My custom MKTileOverlayRenderer class:

```
class ExploredTileRenderer: MKTileOverlayRenderer {

let tile_overlay: ExploredTileOverlay
var zoom_scale: MKZoomScale?
let cache: NSCache = NSCache()

override init(overlay: MKOverlay) {
    self.tile_overlay = overlay as! ExploredTileOverlay
    super.init(overlay: overlay)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(saveEditedTiles), name: "com.Coder.Wander.reachedMaxPoints", object: nil)
}

// There's some weird cache-ing thing that requires me to recall it 
// whenever I re-draw over the tile, I don't really get it but it works
override func canDrawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale) -> Bool {
    self.setNeedsDisplayInMapRect(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale)
    return true
}

override func drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext context: CGContext) {
    zoom_scale = zoomScale
    let tile_path = self.tilePathForMapRect(mapRect, andZoomScale: zoomScale)
    let tile_path_string = stringForTilePath(tile_path)
    //print("redrawing tile: " + tile_path_string)
    self.tile_overlay.loadTileAtPath(tile_path, result: {
        data, error in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                let draw_rect = self.rectForMapRect(mapRect)
                CGContextDrawImage(context, draw_rect, image.CGImage)
                var path: [(CGMutablePath, CGFloat)]? = nil
                self.tile_overlay.point_buffer.readPointsWithBlockAndWait({ points in
                    let total = self.getPathForPoints(points, zoomScale: zoomScale, offset: MKMapPointMake(0.0, 0.0))
                    path = total.0
                    //print("number of points: " + String(path!.count))
                })
                if ((path != nil) && (path!.count > 0)) {
                    //print("drawing path")
                    for segment in path! {
                        CGContextAddPath(context, segment.0)
                        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Clear)
                        CGContextSetLineJoin(context, CGLineJoin.Round)
                        CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
                        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, segment.1)
                        CGContextStrokePath(context)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And my helper functions that handle converting between zoomScale, zoomLevel, tile path, and tile coordinates:

```
func tilePathForMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, andZoomScale zoom: MKZoomScale) -> MKTileOverlayPath {
    let zoom_level = self.zoomLevelForZoomScale(zoom)
    let mercatorPoint = self.mercatorTileOriginForMapRect(mapRect)
    //print("mercPt: " + String(mercatorPoint))

    let tilex = Int(floor(Double(mercatorPoint.x) * self.worldTileWidthForZoomLevel(zoom_level)))
    let tiley = Int(floor(Double(mercatorPoint.y) * self.worldTileWidthForZoomLevel(zoom_level)))

    return MKTileOverlayPath(x: tilex, y: tiley, z: zoom_level, contentScaleFactor: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
}

func stringForTilePath(path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> String {
    return String(format: "%d_%d_%d", path.z, path.x, path.y)
}

func zoomLevelForZoomScale(zoomScale: MKZoomScale) -> Int {
    let real_scale = zoomScale / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    var z = Int((log2(Double(real_scale))+20.0))
    z += (Int(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale) - 1)
    return z
}

func worldTileWidthForZoomLevel(zoomLevel: Int) -> Double {
    return pow(2, Double(zoomLevel))
}

func mercatorTileOriginForMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect) -> CGPoint {
    let map_region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect)

    var x : Double = map_region.center.longitude * (M_PI/180.0)
    var y : Double = map_region.center.latitude * (M_PI/180.0)
    y = log10(tan(y) + 1.0/cos(y))

    x = (1.0 + (x/M_PI)) / 2.0
    y = (1.0 - (y/M_PI)) / 2.0

    return CGPointMake(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y))
}
```

This is a pretty obscure error, I think, so haven't had a whole lot of luck finding other people facing similar issues. Anything would help!

Comment: Have you found an answer to this yet? And how did you solve the upside-down of the tiles?